# AWS SES sends same 'bounceRecipients' through SNS mulitple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

after the usual hair pulling efforts, I finally made **`AWS`**`Simple Email Service` push notifications to my **`REST end point`** through ***`SNS`*** and successfully applied the required business logic on those recipients.

### *Points:*

You must be pushing multiple emails to that Recipient that's why more than one (***unique***) bounce notifications are being pushed by *SNS*. 
***Yes***. And every notification has its own **"messageId"**

But why I am getting bounce Notifications for single recipient repeatedly, only, why not other wrong recipients.?

> Response/s is attached:

```
{
   "notificationType": "Bounce",
   "bounce": {
       "bounceType": "Permanent",
       "bounceSubType": "Suppressed",
       "bouncedRecipients": [
           {
               "emailAddress": "abc.xyz.aws@gmail.com",
               "action": "failed",
               "status": "5.1.1",
               "diagnosticCode": "Amazon SES has suppressed sending to this ..."
           }
       ],
       "timestamp": "2017-12-28T07:06:37.106Z",
       "feedbackId": "010101609bef62ff-0f30cac8-ec3c-41f3-9eee-5f7d90ef3c46-000000",
       "reportingMTA": "dns; amazonses.com"
   },
   "mail": {
       "timestamp": "2017-12-28T07:03:44.000Z",
       "source": "abcXYZ@gmail.com",
       "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:com-xyz-9:9696845301:identity/abcXYZ@gmail.com",
       "sourceIp": "10.eee.ppq.lmn",
       "sendingAccountId": "12365498512",
       "messageId": "010101609bf1b35c-889e815e-b84c-4b08-a283-ee5f3e9740f2-000000",
       "destination": ["abc.xyz.aws@gmail.com"]
   }
}
```

> ```
> Another one and all others:
> ```

```
{
   "notificationType": "Bounce",
   "bounce": {
       "bounceType": "Permanent",
       "bounceSubType": "Suppressed",
       "bouncedRecipients": [
           {
               "emailAddress": "abc.xyz.aws@gmail.com",
               "action": "failed",
               "status": "5.1.1",
               "diagnosticCode": "Amazon SES has suppressed sending to this ..."
           }
       ],
       "timestamp": "2017-12-28T07:06:37.106Z",
       "feedbackId": "010101609befa8f5-a41662a5-b84e-4048-bc3a-d1f1469c8f1a-000000",
       "reportingMTA": "dns; amazonses.com"
   },
   "mail": {
       "timestamp": "2017-12-28T07:04:05.192Z",
       "source": "abcXYZ@gmail.com",
       "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:com-xyz-9:9696845301:identity/abcXYZ@gmail.com",
       "sourceIp": "10.eee.ppq.lmn",
       "sendingAccountId": "12365498512",
       "messageId": "010101609bef61bb-310b4f29-0b01-4ecd-b763-b295e26d0732-000000",
       "destination": ["abc.xyz.aws@gmail.com"]
   }
}
```

> For further info:

HTTP end point is is Spring MVC based REST controller.

### Searching:

Through searching I found these:

***1***- [Duplicate delivery/bounce notifications being sent to my SNS topic?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172706)

***2***- [Emails being sent multiple times - can I see AWS logs ?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=598320)

Kindly can any one help/guide or point out what can be the issue?

Hope you people are having a great holiday season.

Answer (score 0):

```
"bounceSubType": "Suppressed",
```

This recipient is on the global suppression list, which means no SES customer can send mail to this address.  It also means that these bounces are handled differently and more quickly than some other kinds of bounces.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/goodbye-blacklist-introducing-the-suppression-list/

The bottom line here is that this bounce is a red flag to you that you need to manage your recipient addresses more carefully.  Continuing to send messages to recipients on the suppression list is a signal to AWS that you may not be monitoring your bounces, or that you may not really be sending messages to people who actually want to receive them... and that in turn could potentially lead to enforcement actions.

> If the emails you send result in excessive bounces, complaints, or other issues, your sending abilities might be placed on probation or suspended. This process is called enforcement.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/e-faq.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Michael. But my question remains same why only one recipient not other wrong recipients too..!

Comment: Bounces occur for different reasons and with different timing.  It is possible that some invalid addresses will require several hours to bounce, others bounce quickly, and still others will actually report as delivered, first, and then bounce later.  Addresses on the suppression list should bounce quickly and consistently.